# VideoJs Ads Referenced Error on Basic Setup

Tags: javascript, html, video.js

Guys just want to ask if anyone can see the problem, I am not sure if I am just tired or getting dumber and dumber from day to day:

```
<body>
    <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="640" height="264"
           poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
           data-setup="{}">
        <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
        <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" type='video/webm' />
        <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
    </video>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../videojs-contrib-ads-master/src/videojs.ads.css">
    <!-- video.js must be in the <head> for older IEs to work. -->
    <script src="../../videojs-contrib-ads-master/video.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js"></script>
    <script src="../../videojs-contrib-ads-master/src/videojs.ads.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        _V_("example_video_1").ready(function () {
            var player = this;
            player.ads(); // initialize the ad framework

        });
    </script>
</body>
```

So this is the code for VideoJs with a plugin for videojsads which can be found here https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-ads

My problem here is, the I am getting an error

Uncaught TypeError: player.ads is not a function

but if you will look into the example on GitHub, you just need to reference the js and use .ads(). I am so confused right now

Comment: check the js load correcly in debug tools

Answer (score 0):

Videojs.ads is only compatible with videojs v4.0+ you are using v3.2.